# What insights can the training and validation losses curve provide for my sound separation model's performance?

Tags: overfitting-underfitting, trainingloss

I trained sound separation model with 10000samples and the same number of sample was used in validation with number of epochs =10 and 32 batch and 4 number of worker using Adam optimizer . I need someone explain to me  the  output training and validation losses curve for my model  shown in below :

[training and validation loss for sound separation model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unvSN.png)